# GLib - main event loop in C++

Tags: c++, android, glib, event-loop

I need to implement my own main event loop in C++ which will be based on GLib library. I don't know where to begin. I studied some materials about GLib, but it doesn't help me to know, how implement event loop. Could somebody give me some advise about it or give me some source code? I basically need to implement GSource and GSourceFuncs from GLib. 
Event loop should be platform independent, but my application will be run on Android. I can't find how event loop is implemented in Android, could somebody explain it to me too? Thanks a lot.

Lukas

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a difficult project. You should probably start by studying the [glib source code](http://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/glib/gmain.c). Most main loops are similar: your program turns over control to them, and they call functions ("callbacks" or "event handlers" in your program when certain events occur.

Do you need to write a glib-based main loop that will integrate with the Android main loop? Why C++? Are you planning to compile it with the Android NDK? It would be easier to answer your question if you were able to give more information.

Comment: I'm starting porting existing C++ application to Android. Therefore I need to implement my own event loop in C++. I will compile the code with Crystax NDK with full C++ library. I need receiving user actions and other events in C++ code.

Comment: I have another question: Where to find how event loop is implemented on Android? Is there any documentation or I need to browse the source code? Thanks.

Comment: @Lukas, I don't know about the Android main loop. I would suggest the Android API documentation or perhaps an Android book. However, I think that it would probably be easier to port your GUI code to Android's main loop and then use an NDK-compiled library for the back end of your application, whatever it is.

Comment: I'd like to know, how the main event loop is implemented in Android
source code, because I need to implement my own event loop in C++ and
Android implementation could be useful for me to help with C++
implementation.